# UDP multicast fails when eth0 disconnect

Tags: udp, localhost, multicast, loopback

When I run this snippet on my Raspberry Pi 3 with Ethernet cable connected it works and sends the message on UDP multicast but when the ethernet is disconnected if gives the error message

```
import socket
from socket import IPPROTO_IPV6
import struct

PORT = 26000
ADDR = 'ff01::1' #IPV6 Multicast Address

addrInfo = socket.getaddrinfo(ADDR, None)[0]
mcast_sock = socket.socket(addrInfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
mcast_sock.setsockopt(IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS, 1)
mcast_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
mcast_sock.bind(('', PORT))

#Join Multicast grp.
group = socket.inet_pton(addrInfo[0], addrInfo[4][0])
mreq = group + struct.pack('@I', 0)
mcast_sock.setsockopt(IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, mreq)

mcast_sock.sendto(b"Message", (ADDR, PORT))
```

Error Message when only Wlan0 interface is up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    mcast_sock.sendto(b"Message", (ADDR, PORT))
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:13:e8:41
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16716 errors:0 dropped:7224 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:408 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1017246 (993.4 KiB)  TX bytes:56739 (55.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:46:bd:14
          inet addr:10.90.128.72  Bcast:10.90.128.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a4dd:c183:1f7a:5f43/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:58481 errors:0 dropped:41915 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5196 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:12027273 (11.4 MiB)  TX bytes:925411 (903.7 KiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that the local routing favored eth0 over wlan0

```
ip -6 route show table local

local ::1 dev lo  proto kernel  metric 256
local ::1 dev lo  proto none  metric 0
local fe80::a4dd:c183:1f7a:5f43 dev lo  proto none  metric 0
ff00::/8 dev eth0  metric 256
ff00::/8 dev wlan0  metric 256
```

Found this solution

[How to send multicast packets via a specfic interface in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798165/how-to-send-multicast-packets-via-a-specfic-interface-in-linux)

so I ran the following command:

```
ip -6 route add ff01::/16 dev lo table local
```

Then it works :)